# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'lightbox_me'

Tags: jquery, object, lightbox

I have seen a lot of people have faced this error but most of them say that it is because jquery is not defined or something like that...

I am facing the same error where as the very same script works for me on the other websites....

I even wrote my function in the lightbox me file but still it gives the error. Then I placed it into the lightbox code itself but of no use...

I am copying and pasting the code here...Most of you people must have the lightbox me code already but I am just posting it for reference...The error occurs in the function "switch_sections" where i call this line

"$("#ajax-loader").lightbox_me();"

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.lightbox_me = function(options) {

        return this.each(function() {

            var
            opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.lightbox_me.defaults, options),
            $overlay = $(),
            $self = $(this),
            $iframe = $('<iframe id="foo" style="z-index: ' + (opts.zIndex + 1) + ';border: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 0; filter: mask();"/>'),
            ie6 = ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 7);

            if (opts.showOverlay) {
                //check if there's an existing overlay, if so, make subequent ones clear
                var $currentOverlays = $(".js_lb_overlay:visible");
                if ($currentOverlays.length > 0){
                    $overlay = $('<div class="lb_overlay_clear js_lb_overlay"/>');
                } else {
                    $overlay = $('<div class="' + opts.classPrefix + '_overlay js_lb_overlay"/>');
                }
            }

            /*----------------------------------------------------
               DOM Building
            ---------------------------------------------------- */
            if (ie6) {
                var src = /^https/i.test(window.location.href || '') ? 'javascript:false' : 'about:blank';
                $iframe.attr('src', src);
                $('body').append($iframe);
            } // iframe shim for ie6, to hide select elements
            $('body').append($self.hide()).append($overlay);


            /*----------------------------------------------------
               Overlay CSS stuffs
            ---------------------------------------------------- */

            // set css of the overlay
            if (opts.showOverlay) {
                setOverlayHeight(); // pulled this into a function because it is called on window resize.
                $overlay.css({
                    position: 'absolute', 
                    width: '100%', 
                    top: 0, 
                    left: 0, 
                    right: 0, 
                    bottom: 0, 
                    zIndex: (opts.zIndex + 2), 
                    display: 'none'
                });
                if (!$overlay.hasClass('lb_overlay_clear')){
                    $overlay.css(opts.overlayCSS);
                }
            }

            /*----------------------------------------------------
               Animate it in.
            ---------------------------------------------------- */
            //
            if (opts.showOverlay) {
                $overlay.fadeIn(opts.overlaySpeed, function() {
                    setSelfPosition();
                    $self[opts.appearEffect](opts.lightboxSpeed, function() {
                        setOverlayHeight();
                        setSelfPosition();
                        opts.onLoad()
                        });
                });
            } else {
                setSelfPosition();
                $self[opts.appearEffect](opts.lightboxSpeed, function() {
                    opts.onLoad()
                    });
            }

            /*----------------------------------------------------
               Hide parent if parent specified (parentLightbox should be jquery reference to any parent lightbox)
            ---------------------------------------------------- */
            if (opts.parentLightbox) {
                opts.parentLightbox.fadeOut(200);
            }


            /*----------------------------------------------------
               Bind Events
            ---------------------------------------------------- */

            $(window).resize(setOverlayHeight)
            .resize(setSelfPosition)
            .scroll(setSelfPosition);

            $(window).bind('keyup.lightbox_me', observeKeyPress);

            if (opts.closeClick) {
                //$overlay.click(function(e) { closeLightbox(); e.preventDefault; });
                $overlay.click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault;
                });
            }
            $self.delegate(opts.closeSelector, "click", function(e) {
                closeLightbox();
                e.preventDefault();
            });
            $self.bind('close', closeLightbox);
            $self.bind('reposition', setSelfPosition);



            /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */


            /*----------------------------------------------------
               Private Functions
            ---------------------------------------------------- */

            /* Remove or hide all elements */
            function closeLightbox() {
                var s = $self[0].style;
                if (opts.destroyOnClose) {
                    $self.add($overlay).remove();
                } else {
                    $self.add($overlay).hide();
                }

                //show the hidden parent lightbox
                if (opts.parentLightbox) {
                    opts.parentLightbox.fadeIn(200);
                }

                $iframe.remove();

                // clean up events.
                $self.undelegate(opts.closeSelector, "click");

                $(window).unbind('reposition', setOverlayHeight);
                $(window).unbind('reposition', setSelfPosition);
                $(window).unbind('scroll', setSelfPosition);
                $(window).unbind('keyup.lightbox_me');
                if (ie6)
                    s.removeExpression('top');
                opts.onClose();
            }


            /* Function to bind to the window to observe the escape/enter key press */
            function observeKeyPress(e) {
                if((e.keyCode == 27 || (e.DOM_VK_ESCAPE == 27 && e.which==0)) && opts.closeEsc) closeLightbox();
            }


            /* Set the height of the overlay
                    : if the document height is taller than the window, then set the overlay height to the document height.
                    : otherwise, just set overlay height: 100%
            */
            function setOverlayHeight() {
                if ($(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
                    $overlay.css({
                        height: $(document).height() + 'px'
                        });
                    $iframe.css({
                        height: $(document).height() + 'px'
                        }); 
                } else {
                    $overlay.css({
                        height: '100%'
                    });
                    if (ie6) {
                        $('html,body').css('height','100%');
                        $iframe.css('height', '100%');
                    } // ie6 hack for height: 100%; TODO: handle this in IE7
                }
            }


            /* Set the position of the modal'd window ($self)
                    : if $self is taller than the window, then make it absolutely positioned
                    : otherwise fixed
            */
            function setSelfPosition() {
                var s = $self[0].style;

                // reset CSS so width is re-calculated for margin-left CSS
                $self.css({
                    left: '50%', 
                    marginLeft: ($self.outerWidth() / 2) * -1,  
                    zIndex: (opts.zIndex + 3)
                });


                /* we have to get a little fancy when dealing with height, because lightbox_me
                    is just so fancy.
                 */

                // if the height of $self is bigger than the window and self isn't already position absolute
                if (($self.height() + 80  >= $(window).height()) && ($self.css('position') != 'absolute' || ie6)) {

                    // we are going to make it positioned where the user can see it, but they can still scroll
                    // so the top offset is based on the user's scroll position.
                    var topOffset = $(document).scrollTop() + 40;
                    $self.css({
                        position: 'absolute', 
                        top: topOffset + 'px', 
                        marginTop: 0
                    })
                    if (ie6) {
                        s.removeExpression('top');
                    }
                } else if ($self.height()+ 80  < $(window).height()) {
                    //if the height is less than the window height, then we're gonna make this thing position: fixed.
                    // in ie6 we're gonna fake it.
                    if (ie6) {
                        s.position = 'absolute';
                        if (opts.centered) {
                            s.setExpression('top', '(document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight) / 2 - (this.offsetHeight / 2) + (blah = document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop) + "px"')
                            s.marginTop = 0;
                        } else {
                            var top = (opts.modalCSS && opts.modalCSS.top) ? parseInt(opts.modalCSS.top) : 0;
                            s.setExpression('top', '((blah = document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop) + '+top+') + "px"')
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (opts.centered) {
                            $self.css({
                                position: 'fixed', 
                                top: '50%', 
                                marginTop: ($self.outerHeight() / 2) * -1
                                })
                        } else {
                            $self.css({
                                position: 'fixed'
                            }).css(opts.modalCSS);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

        });



    };

    $.fn.lightbox_me.defaults = {

        // animation
        appearEffect: "fadeIn",
        appearEase: "",
        overlaySpeed: 250,
        lightboxSpeed: 300,

        // close
        closeSelector: ".close",
        closeClick: true,
        closeEsc: true,

        // behavior
        destroyOnClose: false,
        showOverlay: true,
        parentLightbox: false,

        // callbacks
        onLoad: function() {},
        onClose: function() {},

        // style
        classPrefix: 'lb',
        zIndex: 999,
        centered: false,
        modalCSS: {
            top: '40px'
        },
        overlayCSS: {
            background: 'black', 
            opacity: .3
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
function switch_sections(id_to_show,class_setting_id)
{
    document.getElementById('ajax-loader').style.display="block";
    $("#ajax-loader").lightbox_me();
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('ajax-loader').style.display="none";
        $('#ajax-loader').trigger('close');
    },3000);

    document.getElementById('occupations').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('inductions').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('licenses').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('tickets').style.display='none';

    document.getElementById('occ').className='';
    document.getElementById('inc').className='';
    document.getElementById('lics').className='';
    document.getElementById('tick').className='';



    document.getElementById(id_to_show).style.display='block';
    document.getElementById(class_setting_id).className='active';
}
```

Can any one help me in this?I shall be grateful...

Answer (score 0):

Works for me. Maybe jQuery is being included after your function is defined so it no longer exists.

Comment: It does not work out for me. I have posted it online for your reference. Please check here. [link] (http://inimitablesystems.com/demos/interactin/troyelliott/careers)

Click on any of the 4 tabs on the right side under blog categories and you will get to know what I mean. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Used .live and .die instead of .delegate and .undelegate on the lines that firebug threw at me and it works.